# Run scheduled job in PHP

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am using Cakephp.
I want to run scheduled jobs.
Here's the situation:

User set time for some task on UI (say 1 week).
When the time is over, I want to execute some specific task. Meanwhile, the user can also change the time, and the task should be executed at updated time.

What is the best way (and reliable) to achieve this?

PS: Complexity is not the issue. But the task must always run after specific time under all circumstances.

Comment: One way would / could be to call a php script with cronjob every minute, and then have the called php script execute the tasks that matches the time / settings etc.

Answer (score 4):

- Set the execution date in your table in a field
- Set a status (pending) as well
- Run a [cron job](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/cron-jobs.html) that runs [a CakePHP shell](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells.html) every X seconds or minutes, whatever you need **OR** create a shell that keeps running all time and check the records every X seconds in a loop.
- The shell will process tasks that are configure for an execution date lower than the current date
- Set the status to success or failed depending on the outcome

It's up to you how you want to handle failed tasks and if it's OK if a task executes 10secs later than configured or 10 minutes. There are multiple factors that play into this: Your interval of the cron job / query against the table. Do they have to processed in parallel? Is it OK to process them after each other? Your information is to vague.

Answer (score 2):

The way to do that in CakePHP is to [create a shell](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells.html) and [run it with Cronjobs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/cron-jobs.html).